# Swift String Comparison Showing Wrong Answer

Tags: string, swift, nsstring

I currently have a very short piece of code, but it is not working for some reason... I am new to Swift, but I have coded before and I don't get why my string comparison is wrong.

```
if let string = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            print(string)
            var test = String(string);
            print((test == "a"))
            print((test == "w"))
```

This is my short code segment. 'let string' is basically grabbing data from a serial port and its just single character strings (e.g. a, w, etc.). However, no matter what I do, test == "a", or "w", is returning false even though when I print out the value of test, it is a, or w.

Comment: You could try printing `test.characters` to see if there's maybe any whitespace somewhere.

Comment: Print the _data_, not the string. That will show you what the actual bytes are and you can figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Hm... I don't get how I can debug it so that I can get test to actually equal "a", or "w".

Comment: print(data.lenght). BTW You should use String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)